# Infinite union of closed intervals, is the result opened or closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the union  $\space\bigcup\limits_{n \geq 1} \left[\dfrac{1}{n}; 1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right] $. I considered $\inf\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right )$ and $\sup\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right )$ and got the obtained the result
$$
\space\bigcup\limits_{n \geq 1} \left[\dfrac{1}{n}; 1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right] = \left(0, 1\right).
$$

I'm wondering whether it should be $\left(0, 1\right)$ or $[0;1] $ since one takes the infinite union. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Well, is $0$ in the union, and is $1$ in the union? That is, is $0$ in any of the constituent intervals of the union and is $1$ in any of the constituent intervals of the union?

Comment: @PatrickStevens 0 and 1 are the limits of the respective sequences, my initial thought was that there aren't included so (0, 1).

Comment: @PatrickStevens does this seem reasonable?

Comment: It is $(0,1)$, but I'm not sure you understand why. The important fact is that it's always true that $x \in \cup X_i$ iff there is $i$ such that $x \in X_i$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens my argumentation why it's (0, 1) would be that even though 0 and 1 are the limits of the respective sequences, those points will never be reached. In other words, the infimum of the sequence 1/n = 0 but it's not part of the set describing the members of the sequence. Is this argumentation valid? If not, could you clarify it for me?

Comment: You still aren't explaining *why* it's true. You're just restating that it *is* true.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I said why it's true, namely because $\inf \frac{1}{n}$ is not in the set $\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, same for $\sup 1-\frac{1}{n}$ and since the infinite union yields an interval [inf 1/n, sup 1-1/n] or (...) depending on what I just said. But I don't know whether this argumentation is correct. If not, I would be pleased if you could explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider its complement in $[0,1]$. Let $A^c$ denote the complement of $A$. $(\cup_{n>1} [\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}])^c=\cap_{n>1} [\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}]^c$. Then $x \in \cap_{n>1} [\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}]^c$ only if $0\leq x< \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$ or $1-\frac{1}{n}<x \leq 1$ for all $n$, then either $x=0$ or $x=1$. Thus $(\cup_{n>1} [\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}])^c=\{0,1\}$. So $\cup_{n>1} [\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}]=(0,1)$.